# How do I override default nlog configuration?

Tags: nlog

We ship a framework assembly for logging which internally uses nlog. We also ship an embedded nlog configuration as a resource in our assembly and read this on startup (a static constructor within our wrapper which wraps over the nlog wrapper using the XmlLoggingConfiguration class).

We would now like developers to be able to specify/override additional configuration via an external file for their own loggers (using the same nlog configuration file format).

Can we:

- Refer include files in our embedded nlog configuration file? How is the path of the include file resolved? If we do this, does the content of the include file override the content of the embedded nlog configuration we read on startup?
- Can developers use the nlog configuration section? Does the content of this section override the default configuration we have specified pro grammatically?

Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

> How is the path of the include file resolved?

You can use in the included file name:

1. layout renderers such as `${baseDir}`,
2. [nlog variables](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables).

If the resulting filename is not absolute, it is combined with the directory, where the original NLog configuration was located, but this may be null in your case, so you are limited to first 2 options.

> does the content of the include file override the content of the embedded nlog configuration?

No, this content is added to the content of the embedded configuration.

> Does the content of nlog configuration section override the default configuration we have specified programmatically?

When you set the configuration programatically, you override any configuration that was set before and also disable the automatic configuration discovery, including one from application configuration file or NLog.config.

But you can check whether the configuration is not null first time before you set the embedded value. This will trigger the automatic discovery, and in case if any logging configuration is found, the returned value would be non-null.